# XSL: Displaying attributes of the current node

Tags: xslt, xpath, soap, identitymanager, netiq

I am using NetIQ's Identity Manager.  I want to modify the return response to display all of the attributes of the current node.  The current node is a user ID which will be different 99.999% of the time.

I found the section of code to where I can add this information.

```
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:message>Output: Add SOAP Headers</xsl:message>
            <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
                <soap-env:Body>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                    *<xsl:text>I am here</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                      attribute name:
                      <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                      attribute value:
                      <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </xsl:for-each>*
                </soap-env:Body>
            </soap-env:Envelope>
        </xsl:otherwise>
```

the code I added is in Italic.  Here is the output:

```
   <soap-env:Body>
      <batchResponse xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <errorResponse requestID="0" type="successful">
            <message>DirXMLwdStudiodev\users\dev800055Publisher</message>
            <detail>success</detail>
         </errorResponse>
      </batchResponse>
      I am hereDirXMLwdStudiodev\users\dev800055Publisher
                          attribute name:
                          dest-dn
                          attribute value:

                          attribute name:
                          event-id
                          attribute value:
                          0
                          attribute name:
                          level
                          attribute value:
                          success
   </soap-env:Body>
```

Any ideas on how to reference and print the attributes of the user ID.  It seems that I am printing the event information.  Thanks in advance for any help/pointers.

Frank

Comment: Please post also the source XML.

Comment: I pasted the XML here:
https://pastebin.com/XqYPdFuM